# The result codes in trace mode(line to line) is different with its execution in normal state

Tags: javascript, trace

there's something strange going on here.
The result of running the following codes in trace mode(line to line) is different with its execution in normal state...!
how could that be possible?
These lines are part of commands for reading and execution the barcodeScanner input and proccessed somethings in my project..

```
function decodeBarcode(code) {
   ... Something codes ...
   var focuedItemIsResponce = (rowItemCode.includes(code) && itemCodeFocused == responseValues.ItemCode);
   if (rowItemCode == responseValues.ItemCode || focuedItemIsResponce) {

      ... Something procceess ...

      if (focuedItemIsResponce) {  //this condition is Event occurrence

           ... Something codes ...
       }
    }
```

When I tracing the codes in browser's Inspect and landing to codes that pointed by comment, everything is working and condition is checked and run commands..That means if " focuedItemIsResponce " variable is true codes in condition block is running and Everything is done according to normal procedure..

But when closing the inpect and run the program, codes of inside condition block is not running..!!!

I 've tried several times and confident in terms of the variable value.
 . But it appears that condition is not checking

can you comment on this problem?

Comment: `But when closing the inpect and run the program`? You mean after page refresh?

Comment: No.. these codes run when I scanned a barcodeNumber with scanner.I once run this with opening inspect and then run that when inpect is closing..

Comment: I even test this: I put breakpoint in code of below that and check value of " focuedItemIsResponce  " and that's true.. If I closing inpect to go on, condition block is not running..!!!

Comment: Opening/closing developer tool does not affect your code. How come you know the code inside `focuedItemIsResponce` is not executing? Try printing some dummy text inside the `if block`. It would be great if you could reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have a table in page that values of it's cells is editing by codes of inside condition block.. when developer tool is open, values are editing, but when it is close, no editing is occured

Comment: This sounds really crazy. I would insist you to reproduce the issue, to determine the exact cause of issue.

Comment: `rowItemCode.includes(code)` implies that `rowItemCode` is an Array - but on the very next line you compare it `rowItemCode == responseValues.ItemCode` which implies that `rowItemCode` is probably not an Array. Perhaps this is the culprit ?